# Can a JFET replace a IGFET? (A 3N139 IGFET)

Tags: mosfet, jfet

it is my first question so please forgive my errors. I try to build the People Detector from Popular Electronics http://www.swtpc.com/mholley/PopularElectronics/Jun1968/PE_Jun_1968_pg28.jpg. The 3N139 is obsolete and i search to replace it. I found from a book the FET 3N128 again obsolete and for 3N128 is the JFET 2N3966 (i get it). For the Q2 i ll use a BC548B. My question is can a JFET with similar characteristics replace a MOSFET? Because https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_5.html mentions that; "It is essential that the Gate voltage is never positive since if it is all the channel current will flow to the Gate and not to the Source, the result is damage to the JFET".  From this i get that it cant replace for all applications the FET. Is it right? Does the Q2 used here as diode zener will protect it from this situation too?

Comment: Your project needs a really high input impedance to work well .The mosfet will be best .

Answer (score 2):

You could try a JFET but the gate leakage current may be too high. The junction between the gate and the channel is a PN junction so there will be a small but significant leakage current. A MOSFET on the other hand will have an extremely low gate current. You could try a dual gate FET intended for RF applications, with the unused gate either tied to the other gate or the source. These are depletion devices too. Something like the BF994S, which is surface mount. Not sure what through hole parts are around these days. Yes, I think the transistor is there to limit the gate voltage and also perhaps to provide weak bias.

Comment: You're welcome. The datasheet for 2N3966 states that the continuous gate current should not exceed 10 mA. I would assume that currents below this would not damage the device.

Comment: The original FET 3N139 according to this <https://www.datasheetarchive.com/pdf/download.php?id=1d35a533fa20b995305ccec6f440ce7bcbd193&type=M&term=3N139> has Id max 50mA and the 3N128 25 mA. If the 2N3966 is rejected "due to positive voltage will destroy it" do you think BF994 will match? And for BF994 they stopped production.

Comment: You could try LND150N3-G, which is N channel depletion, through hole, with low junction capacitance and available.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot use a JFET to replace a MOSFET.

The exception is depletion mode MOSFETS 
and then only if the JFET is compatible with the gate voltages used it could work,
if the gate gets forward biased current will flow into the gate. Depending on the application it might be possible to sufficiently protect against that using a gate resistor

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So a depletion N channel JFET will be destroyed with positive voltage at gate.